# Atom: Javascript shows "ReferenceError: document is not defined" after putting code on body HTML

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor

Javascript script shows :

> ReferenceError: document is not defined when I run this code

[ReferenceError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuDux.png)

**HTML and JS**:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#click')

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  alert('clicked')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="click" name="button">click me</button>
    <script src="Pracitce.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also when I run `HTML` on Chrome browser, the click event doesn't fire anything. How can I connect my two files into one? What is wrong after putting 'script' with sources?

Comment: Probably because Atom does not have a document, but your code works fine in a browser. Check the console for errors. Your path to your js file might be wrong.

Comment: @Gwen Lee how did you run it when you received the error?

Comment: @Aalexander I used 'Script' package install from atom-ide-community - and used Run Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser `window` object has document property in it, you need to link your JS file with your HTML file and then run your HTML file and view the output in the browser.

You can also use `console` in your browser to run your sample JS code.

[You can learn more about the `document` object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)